# Ошибка Programg g++ not found in PATH readwritepaths

Tags: c++, eclipse, компиляция

Создал проект в eclipse Juno Hello World Autotools C++ Project. Удалил из него ненужную часть и вставил в него свою программу

```
#include <iostream>

//using namespace std;

#include <stdio.h>
#include <postgresql/libpq-fe.h>
#include <string>
#include <cstdio>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <libc.h>

int     main() {
PGconn          *conn;
PGresult        *res;
int             rec_count;
int             row;
int             col;
FILE            *stream;

conn = PQconnectdb("hostaddr=192.168.143.93 port=5432 connect_timeout=5 dbname=NexentaSearch user=DKOI
 password=21111991");
if (PQstatus(conn) == CONNECTION_BAD) {
    puts("Не удается подключиться к базе данных");
    exit(0);
}

res = PQexec(conn, "select path from paths order by id");

if (PQresultStatus(res) != PGRES_TUPLES_OK) {
    printf("Мы не получили данные");
    exit(0);
}

rec_count = PQntuples(res);

printf("Мы получили %d записей.\n", rec_count);
puts("==========================");

stream=fopen("usr/local/paths.txt", "w");
for (row=0; row<rec_count; row++) {
    for (col=0; col<1; col++) {
        fprintf(stream, "%s\n", PQgetvalue(res, row, col));
    }
    puts("");
}

puts("==========================");
PQclear(res);
PQfinish(conn);
return 0;
```

}

При компиляции (щелчке на молотке Build 'Build (GNU)' for project readwritepaths) выдает следующие ошибки:

> Error 127 occurred while running autoreconf readwritepaths -1 Configure Problem
>
> Programg g++ not found in PATH readwritepaths
>
> Programg gcc not found in PATH readwritepaths

Comment: @ivan31, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.

Comment: gcc и g++ установлены? Если нет - установите!

Comment: каким образом устанавливать gcc и g++ на Windows?

Comment: Скачайте MinGW, пропишите MinGW\bin в PATH.

Comment: А причем тут линукс в тегах?

Answer (score 2):

Для начала установите компиляторы g++/gcc. Потом в эклипсе нужно пути к компиляторам прописать.

Comment: @Re1aps через какие пункты меню в eclipse Juno надо прописать пути?